# Re-Enable localhost privileges on MySQL

Tags: mysql, localhost, privileges

I work with **XAMPP** and by mistake I deleted all privileges for `localhost` in MySQL so I can't use the `localhost` to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO *.* root@localhost` since I'm doing this in the `localhost`. I remember a User with full privileges and Its password but I can't do much since the `localhost` has no privileges at all and if I use the MYSQL Shell it tells me the same thing

I didn't enable remote access when I installed the **XAMPP** so it could be also a problem (Or maybe not and there is a solution within my machine).

Is there a way to access to `mysql.user` in some way to enable again the privileges for my `localhost`, or do it using the MySQL shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. stop server
2. start server with `–skip-grant-tables` key
3. connect to server as `root` without password
4. edit privileges table:

   ```
   USE mysql;
   UPDATE user SET host='localhost' WHERE user=’root’ LIMIT 1;
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
5. start server in normal mode

Comment: Hi SliChan, I deleted the root privileges as well but I have a user & passwd with full privileges
1.I Stopped Apache (MySql running);
2.Started server with –skip-grant-tables in a 1st window - C:...\bin\mysql –skip-grant-tables 3.I used user root with no –p (It has no rights so I used my other user and everything looks fine. 4.Use mysql ok, DB Changed ok, UPDATE ok, all ok. Finally I Flushed the PRIVILEGES. 5. Then I start the server. 6.No luck. MySQL Localhost still with No privileges. What could it be the problem? hanks man.
[link](http://postimage.org/image/9ypkc82g5/full/

Comment: Try to truncate users table and insert new record for root:
`INSERT INTO user VALUES ('%','root','','Y',''Y',...etc...)` in `–skip-grant-tables key mode`. Also `GRANT` command may work: `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password'`, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: The truncate seems to be the solution, I'm just having a sintax error, I'm using MySQL 5.5.8 and this instructions are for MySQL 5.2 INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('localhost','root','','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','',0,0,0,0); (TOTAL: Local,root,empty,28 Y, 4empty,4 zeros)[link](http://postimage.org/image/5eyumof2p/)  Thanks for your time and help man.

Comment: Sorry, I've seem that I used '' with user, here is the right INSERT line, but now the problems is that Columns doesn't match as you can see in this [link to image](http://postimage.org/image/sad85emp1/)

Comment: Hi SlyChan, I've got the count of Ys, blanks and zeros [image with count](http://postimage.org/image/qdh3d9n1l/) using SELECT * From user, but I can't get the right count. Would you please check this setting or count?. Thanks for any help man. Greetings.

Comment: But what am I seeing here is that will also just update the privilegies for users at localhost, but what I need is set the localhost privileges in order to be able to see my databases. Hope you can help me. Greetings.

Comment: Hi SlyChan, GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password' did the job, but I clened my cache and then the sessions get the changes (Silly me). Man really thanks for you help and time. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

If you can restart MySQL server then follow these steps - [How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Comment: Didn't this link help, or was it incorrect? -1 should be explained.

Comment: Devart thanks for your time, but actually my problem it’s not about change passwords (I know them) my problem is that I deleted all privileges for (Localhost, 127.0.0.1, root), and the localhost privileges are what I want to be ok, since I can’t access my databases using the localhost. If you have any idea It will be great.

Comment: You can use this solution to access and to modify securuty tables as you want - to change passwords, to add, modify or drop user.

Comment: Hi Devart, your asnwer as well was right cause they reach this issue in the link. Thans buddie.